# DOXYGEN: Insert special characters in English output file

Tags: doxygen

I'm generating a Doxygen file in English ( OUTPUT_LANGUAGE      = English), but sometimes I need to include special characters of other languages (i.e. 'ñ', 'ö', etc. ). The problem is when using these characters, the generated file replaces these characters by unknown characters: �

So, how can include special characters in an English output Doxygen document?

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Eduardo

Comment: which vesrion of doxygen are you using? Did you have a look at the chapter (24) "HTML commands" of the manual e.g. &ntilde; ?

Comment: Or check and adjust INPUT_ENCODING. It is probably not set to the encoding you use (doxygen's default is UTF-8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help

Changing INPUT_ENCODING to ISO-8859-1 fixes the problem.

Hope this helps